# Adjacent div overlap on top of each other using CSS transform property and transition

Tags: html, css, animation, transform

I am using CSS transform property scaleX for my animation. See [CodePen](https://codepen.io/audhit/pen/RZpbdq). Unfortunately the red box on the left has no effects on hover and its not transforming like the other 3 ones. From my understanding, as the red box has no space on it's left that is why it cannot transform on hover. Is there any good solution for my problem?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="image image1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="image image2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="image image3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="image image4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also reset `z-index` on `:hover` and eventually `transform-origin` for the first and last element:

```css
.image1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.image2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.image3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.image4 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.image {
  height: 15vw;
}

.img-holder {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.img-holder .image {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.img-holder .image:hover {
  transform: scaleX(2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.col-sm-3:first-of-type :hover .image {
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.col-sm-3:last-of-type :hover .image {
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="image image1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="image image2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="image image3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <div class="image image4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dzvypQ